# Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция ifstream

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

В fname хранится путь к файлу, файл .txt
[image: Проблема]

Comment: Не надо смешивать C++/CLI и чистый C++. Если хотите работать с [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/), то используйте `std::string`. Но раз уж вы пишете на _управляемой_ версии языка, то возьмите типы из [System.IO Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: А есть другие способы(без ifstream) отправить данные файла в переменную?

Comment: [ReadAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_)